# Left hand side function with R

Tags: r, function

In R, is it possible to write functions that be behaves like colnames?
eg. I would like a function, say 'foo' that could be used as :
    `x <- foo("y")` # reads the contents of the file "y" into x
or
  `foo("y") <- x` # writes the contents of x into the file "y"
How can I catch the fact that the function is the first argument of `<-`? Should I refine the `<-`(dangerous)? And how to make the following work as expected?
  `x -> foo("y")`
... and of course I don't want two different functions (read and write) : my purpose is to introduce a new syntax inspired by the base R.

Thanks

Comment: The parser actually supports something similar for subsetting (e.g., functions `\`[\`` and `\`[<-\``) but I don't think you can have an arbitrary function as the LHS of assignment in R.

Comment: I tried to define a 'foo<-' for the write operation (foo on lhs), but it is not recognized.

Comment: Of course it isn't. The parser does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the parse DOES support arbitrary functions as the LHS of assignment but these functions to something that can be used itself in left hand side (such as a variable name but not a string or a numeric litteral), so the code :

```
`foo<-` <- function(x,y,value) set_foo(x,y,value)
 set_foo <- function(x,y,value) UseMethod("set_foo")
 set_foo.data.frame <- function(x,y,value)  {print(x);print(y);print(value);x}

 data(mtcars)
 foo(mtcars,1)<-2
```

works fine, but

```
foo(0,1)<-2
```

will result on error even with a set_foo.default being defined.